# File "<string>", line 6, in <module> ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher

Tags: module, cryptography, line, importerror, encryption

I try to install "Userful MultiSeat-X64-5.0.1 ..." in Ubuntu 04.12 LTS x64, and encountered the following error at the end of the installation:

```
File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? I hope you help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the pycrypto module

pip install pycrypto

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for long years to reply. Obligation against my decision and permission in 2013 to now (2023), block my life in Portugal. I'm forced to use drugs pharmaceutics without having problems in mind. Doctors and PSP Police lies